# AutoMapper Circular reference ,how do i Map it

Tags: c#, reference, automapper, circular-reference, navigation-properties

i am using WPF,EF,AutoMapper...
i have a problem with how i Map Dto to Entity what the Dto has circular Reference. 
i am tried to Maped like this

```
public class AProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        CreateMap<DtoA, A>().MaxDepth(1);
        CreateMap<DtoB, B>().MaxDepth(1);
        CreateMap<DtoC, C>().MaxDepth(1);
    }
}
```

but it dose not work.

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddProfile<AProfile>());
var As = db.ADtos.ProjectTo<ADto>(config).ToList();
```

**the As[0] is not null, but the As[0].Bs is null,please help me!**

```
namespace Opt
{
    public class ADto
    {
        public int Id {get;set;}
        public virtual List<BDto> Bs{get;set;}
        public virtual List<CDto> Cs{get;set;}
    }
    public class BDto
    {
        public int Id {get;set;}

        public int AId {get;set;}
        public virtual ADto A {get;set;}

        public virtual List<CDto> Cs{get;set;}
    }
    public class CDto
    {
        public int Id {get;set;}

        public int AId {get;set;}
        public virtual ADto A {get;set;}

        public int BId {get;set;}
        public virtual BDto B {get;set;}
    }
}
namespace Dest
{
    public class A
    {
        public int Id {get;set;}
        public virtual List<B> Bs{get;set;}
        public virtual List<C> Cs{get;set;}
    }
    public class B
    {
        public int Id {get;set;}

        public int AId {get;set;}
        public virtual A A {get;set;}

        public virtual List<C> Cs{get;set;}
    }
    public class C
    {
        public int Id {get;set;}

        public int AId {get;set;}
        public virtual A A {get;set;}

        public int BId {get;set;}
        public virtual B B {get;set;}
    }
}
```